# Block region not outputting anything?

Tags: 7, blocks

I have this on my template:

```
  <?php print render($page['left']); ?>
```

And no matter how many blocks I add to the left sidebar region, nothing prints.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which template?

Comment: A custom page.tpl. page--type--collection.tpl to be exact.

Comment: Did you put it also at themes info file?

Comment: No. Do I need to? I don't have header in the .info file and it works as a block region.

Comment: Yeah. It's definitely using the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah. Finally figured it out. The Left Sidebar is actually called sidebar_first. DSM'ed the $page variable.